# Bitmap is null after calling decodeByteArray(response, 0, response.length)

Tags: android, android-bitmap

The byte array is valid as the response is working iOS devices.
I am not able to convert it as Bitmap is alway null.

`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(response, 0, response.length);`

> byte array length - 86842

I checked other answers but all are pointing invalid byte array. Mine is not.

```
InputStreamRequest api = new InputStreamRequest(Request.Method.POST, imageURL, new Response.Listener<byte[]>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(byte[] response)
            {
                Log.e( TAG ,"imageURL response : " + response );
                dismissCustomDialog();
                try
                {
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(response, 0, response.length, options );
                    Log.e( TAG ,"Length : " + response.length );
                    Log.e( TAG ,"Bitmap : " + bitmap );
                    imageView.setImageBitmap( bitmap );
                }
                catch( Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e( TAG , "image exc. " + e.toString() );
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                dismissCustomDialog();
                tv_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue volleyQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( context);
        volleyQueue.add(api);
```

Comment: do you mean `response = 86842`  and `bitmap = null`

Comment: byte array length is 86842 (coming from webservice) and bitmap is null after calling decodeByteArray

Comment: Please, provide the url or an example of the picture. In all cases it means you feed the decoder by incorrect byte array.

Comment: The URL is not GET and has auth token, so can not give you. Any random image is fine, because the same image (byte array)is working fine in iOS and Website.

Comment: Is received data the same in iOS? Possibly, you send incorrect request and the services receives the incorrect response. I would suggest try to save the binary data into a file and try to open the file somewhere outside the device.

Comment: No. The same web-services is accessed by other devices too.

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() catches internal errors and exceptions so you mostly will not know what causes it to return a null. Often though you can see stacktraces in the LogCat which give you info. Often a null is returned because the Bitmap would not fit in memory. Saving the bytes to file to see what you have is indeed a good idea.

Comment: `The same web-services is accessed by other devices too` That can be. But maybe you access them different. Start with downloading the same picture and compare the amount of bytes. You have 86842. How much is it on iOs?

Comment: For the rest you could show your code which receives the bytes and puts them in response. Could save you and us a lot of time. Show your complete request please.

Comment: Your code looks ok. So now do what we asked you to do and also give the info we asked for.